# Workaround for UTC DateTime Offset with ReadXML

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, frameworks

I'm using the following code and getting an offset date.

```
HistDataTable.ReadXml("HisFile.xml");
```

When it reads this line `<ContractDate>1998-10-26T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</ContractDate>` it converts it to this `10/25/1998 11:00:00 PM`.  It subtracts an hour which in turn is changing the date from the 26th to the 25th.  It does this during the `ReadXML` operation.

I could write in my code to add an hour to the variable, but it doesn't do this to all the records.  Out of 190,000 records it only does this to 30,000.  The old version written in VS2003 doesn't do this. VS2012 does.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to work around it?

Comment: It sounds like it is adjusting the time from/to UTC  do all of the lines contain the same time offset (the '-05:00' on the end)?

Comment: Yes all the records have this -05:00 at the end.  But it doesn't do the converting to all the records.  <ContractDate>2013-08-28T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</ContractDate> doesn't convert at all.